# How to use alias in where clause in mysql

Tags: mysql

Are there any other way of doing this query:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", strLname, strFname, strMname) AS lessor_name 
FROM tbl_lessor 
WHERE lessor = '$lessor_name'
```

I tried it but got an error it says unknown column in mysql

Comment: Which column is unknown?

Comment: @Kyoka Suigetsu :paste full error msg here.

Comment: Your alias is called `lessor_name` but you are referencing it as `lessor` (not that aliases can be used in `WHERE` anyway though MySQL does allow them in `HAVING`)

Comment: sorry that was just a typo its supposed to be WHERE lessor_name. Using HAVING solved the problem thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be due to `lessor` instead of  `lessor_name` in where clause. So try with below once :

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", strLname, strFname, strMname) AS lessor_name 
FROM tbl_lessor 
having lessor_name= '$lessor_name'
```

Answer (score 4):

In MySQL, you cannot use the alias near **WHERE**.

Answer (score 2):

maybe this will work:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", strLname, strFname, strMname) AS lessor_name  
FROM tbl_lessor  
WHERE CONCAT_WS(" ", strLname, strFname, strMname) = '$lessor_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONCAT_WS(" ", strLname, strFname, strMname) AS lessor_name 
FROM tbl_lessor) AS t1 
WHERE lessor_name = '$lessor_name'
```